# Using Swift, how can I get the x-coordinate of an NSTableColumn while it is being dragged

Tags: swift, nstableview, nstableviewheader

I've tried using KVO on `NSTableHeaderView.draggedDistance` but didn't get anywhere - I might be incorrect but I assume because it is a computed property. `NSTableView` has `.rect(ofColumn:)` but as far as I'm aware this is also not something I can track. `tableViewColumnDidMove(_ notification: Notification)` only triggers once the column is released and `func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, shouldReorderColumn columnIndex: Int, toColumn newColumnIndex: Int) -> Bool` only runs when the column index changes positions (for instance, when column index 2 becomes column index 3), not while its position value (in points/pixels) changes. Any pointers?

Comment: I think it's not possible. Hacky undocumented workaround: subclass `NSTableHeaderView` and override `draggedDistance` or `draggedColumn`.

Comment: I tried that actually - but got an error when trying to override draggedDistance's setter as it doesn't have one (but I am interested in doing something when that value changes/is-being-set)

Comment: `draggedDistance` is called repeatedly.

Comment: Ah right, yes using the `get` seems to work. That'll solve my issue, thanks!